# How to update a URL in xcode project without having to build the application again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an application which hits the server for communication. In case, my server address changes, i want to incorporate that changed address in the application from the device itself.

I dont want to build my application again and sync it with itunes and then with my device.
As an administrator, i want to update the url from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using NSUserDefaults and a Settings Bundle to modify the URL.  It would then be a user preference which can have a sensible default, but then can be changed from outside the app without recompilation.  See the "Implementing Application Preferences" section of Apple's iOS Application Programming Guide.

Comment: This would require the user of the app to change the value. Sounded like he wanted only the app creator to be able to modify it. Is this correct, @samarth?

Answer (score 0):

If my comment to Christian's answer is valid, why don't you use an actual domain name instead of a server address? Then it doesn't matter if your IP changes.